# Linux. Apache2. Права доступа на директорию /var/www/

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, permissions

По умолчанию на Ubuntu 14.04 у папки `/var/www/` права следующие `drwxr-xr-x root root`
Но с такими правами на локальной машине разрабатывать неудобно.

Выставить `chmod 777` не хочу из соображений безопасности.

Как выставить права для локальной разработки с учетом того что сервер работает из под www-data? 
То есть требуется что бы у двух пользователей одновременно были одинаковые полные права (777) на `/var/www/` - у www-data и у пользователя под которым я работаю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На самом деле есть несколько способов. Первый, банальный - использовать локальный апач. Способ хорош, но для нормальной разработки очень неудобен и один с примеров неудобности Вы описали. Можно пойти дальше и сделать себе папку в домашнем каталоге и поправить конфиг апача, но это тоже плохо. Поэтому, я даже не буду расписывать этот способ детально.

Более продвинутый способ - это использовать реальный сервер. Но он также плох. Сервер обычно не бесплатный и лаги с доступом. Но я видел человека, который собрал себе кластер на raspberry pi и радуется. А также закупился десятком sdcard, где хранит различные дистрибутивы.

А самый простой и правильный способ - использовать докер. Рассмотрим плюсы:

- очень легко собрать нужную конфигурацию (базу данных с нужной версией, апач с правильным конфигом, нужную ось).
- если написать compose файл, то очень легко передать "соседу" или админу, что бы себе развернули.
- Легко держать несколько различных "сайтов", а не городить город с конфигами.
- докер доступен не только для линукса, а и для макоси, а недавно стал доступен и для Виндовса, а это позволяет много.
- многие хостеры сейчас предоставляют хостинг для докера. То есть, процесс заливки своего сайта на подобный хостинг сводиться к копированию dockerfile или compose файла и его запуска.

Как все это настроить и запустить. Прежде всего нужно поставить докер и, желательно `docker-compose`. Тут читайте маны к вашей оси.

Дальше, нужно решить, как "заливать сорцы". Тут есть несколько способов.

- хардкор - установить в докере вим/нано/эмакс и разрабатывать прям в нем. Но это для любителей. Но у этого способа есть свои плюсы. Среда разработки может спокойно мигрировать между компьютерами.
- простой. Докер образ может использовать папку с хост машины. То есть, папку с проектом подключаем в докер. Для этого есть два способа - либо просто подключить в докер файле (`ADD /host/path /path/inside/docker/container`) или при старте контейнера (`docker run -v /host/directory:/container/directory ...`). А можно при старте контейнера копировать файлы. Если правильно все скомпоновать, то все будет жить в контейнере и в рабочем каталоге. А если докер правильно настроить, то даже рут прав не нужно.
- сложный, но красивый. Красивый и правильный способ заключается в том, что нужно встроить свою систему "деплоя". Этот способ для мелких проектов излишний, но для более сложных окупается. На самом начальном этапе пишется скрипт, который умеет заливать файлы и производить нужные манипуляции (выставлять права, перезапускать апач, править базу). А сам скрипт запускается либо руками, либо цепляется к хуку на коммит/пуш.

А теперь, список полезных ссылок.

- собственно сайт [докера](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/userguide/).
- как настроить себе окружение для работы с [апач, пхп и мускулем](http://blog.osteel.me/posts/2015/12/18/from-vagrant-to-docker-how-to-use-docker-for-local-web-development.html).
- и ещё одна статья на эту тему [docker for php developers](http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/docker-for-php-developers).
- статья [на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/247547/), где рассказывается также как настроить dnsmask, который позволит сделать локальный dns и тестировать свои наработки с реальными адресами и без модификации hosts файла.